# Finding the word that corresponds to experience

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, part-of-speech

Suppose i have a sentence like the following, how can i find what the experience corresponds to?

Ex: Programmer with 5 years of experience wanted.
I want to find what the experience (5 years) corresponds to, in this case programmer.

The code should also be recognize a corresponding verb, ex: 5 years of programming

So how should i go about it? I was thinking of making a pattern that finds the closest noun or verb.

Comment: it should also be able to recognize corresponding chunks such as Java programming

Comment: This is a very broad question. What specific formats are you looking to handle? (Imagine things like "Wanted: 5-year experienced programmer" or "Programmer with 5 years of project management and 10 years of programming experience"; what's in-scope for your needs?). What have you tried so far?

Comment: As of now i am able to extract the experience part, so i want to know what experience a candidate has.

Comment: For something like  "Programmer with 5 years of project management and 10 years of programming experience", I should get project management for 5 years and programming experience for 10- years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't get any meaningful help, I just came up with a temporary solution of my own. Find the sentence with the entity tag "DATE", and remove the stop words.

For example, the sentence 'The ideal candidate must have at least 6 years of experience in the field.' becomes into the following:

'ideal candidate 6 years experience field'

Obviously I can refine this further, but for now this will do.